# How to wrap a xmlrpc function call?

Tags: python, wrapper, xml-rpc, xmlrpcclient

I have a simple `xmlrpc` server defined as (`server.py`):

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer

def foo():
    return "foo"

server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 1025))
server.register_introspection_functions()
server.register_function(foo, 'test.foo')
server.serve_forever()
```

and the client (`client.py`) implemented as follows:

```
import xmlrpclib

class XMLRPC(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.xmlrpc = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:1025/RPC2")

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        attr = getattr(self.xmlrpc, name)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            result = attr(*args, **kwargs)
            return result
        return wrapper

xmlrpc = XMLRPC()
print xmlrpc.test.foo()
```

I want to wrap and execute each call that is being made to the `xmlrpc` server within the class `XMLRPC`. But the above working example gives an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 20, in <module>
    xmlrpc.test.foo()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

How to make this code work?

Additional information and constraints:

- I already tried to wrap `wrapper` with `functools.wraps(attr)` without succcess. As the string `attr` has no attribute `__name__` I get a different error
- I canot change anything defined in `server.py`.
- The above example is fully working.
- Replacing `return wrapper` by `return attr` is not a solution - I need to execute the actual `xmlrpc` call within `wrapper`.
- I need a simple solution without a 3rd party library, standard python libs are ok.

Comment: Can you update the exception to show the **full** traceback?

Comment: Done, and added the missing line in which `XMLRPC` is instantiated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return a callable object instead.

The XML-RPC proxy returns an instance of an object that is callable, but can also be traversed over. So for `xmlrpc.test.foo()`, you are wrapping `xmlrpc.test` in a function; that function object does not have a `foo` attribute because functions generally don't have such attributes.

Return a proxy object instead; the `__call__` hook makes it a callable object, just like a function would be:

```
class WrapperProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.wrapped = wrapped

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        attr = getattr(self.wrapped, name)
       return type(self)(attr)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        return self.wrapped(*args, **kw)

class XMLRPC(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.xmlrpc = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:1025/RPC2")

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        attr = getattr(self.xmlrpc, name)
        return WrapperProxy(attr)
```

or, merged into one object:

```
class XMLRPCWrapperProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped=None):
        if wrapped is None: 
            wrapped = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:1025/RPC2")
        self.wrapped = wrapped

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        attr = getattr(self.wrapped, name)
       return type(self)(attr)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        return self.wrapped(*args, **kw)
```

Comment: Finally it seems to work. Thank you very much. I appreciate you answering python questions on a 24/7 basis, it seems...