# XMLRPC server functions wrapper

Tags: python, wrapper, xml-rpc

I'm trying to wrap my xml-rpc server (python 2.7)
and i'm using the code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17297464/1982962)

This is my code:

```
class XMLRPCWrapperProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped=None):
        if wrapped is None:
            wrapped = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx')
        self.tf = wrapped

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print "before"
        attr = getattr(self.tf, name)
        print "after"
        return type(self)(attr)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        return self.tf(*args, **kw)

server_w = XMLRPCWrapperProxy()

server_w.tf.do_function1()
server_w.tf.do_function2(param1)
server_w.tf.do_function3()
server_w.tf.do_function4(param1)
```

I want to `wrap do_fuxntion...` call but for some reason i can't see the print statements, i think i'm wrapping self.tf and not the call methods, any idea how can i warp any method call?

Comment: Down voter, can you explain your down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wrap `tf`, why do you call `server_w.tf` in your tests?
That makes the wrapping kind of pointless.

If you try `server_w.do_function1()` you'll see the print-statements.
I don't understand what you're trying to achieve with the `type(self)(attr)`line though...

I'd try `__getattr__` simply like this:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    print "before"
    attr = getattr(self.tf, name)
    print "after"
    return attr
```

This should properly return the function of the wrapped object.

Comment: I think the `type(self)(attr)` is meant to automatically wrap any return value from the method calls. (edit: nah, that doesn't make complete sense if I look at it more closely...)

Answer (score 1):

This might be fairly obvious, but you can't see the print statements, because the `__getattr__` method is never called. I suspect your calls should leave out the `.tf` part, if I understand the intent correctly. Thus it should read:

```
# ...
server_w.do_function1()
server_w.do_function2(param1)
server_w.do_function3()
server_w.do_function4(param1)
```